# Encrypt data from PHP using TSHAK or an alternative method

Tags: php, asp.net, encryption

I need to encrypt data from PHP using TSHAK, this data is going to be sent to a ASP page.

I am a newbi with all the encryption thing. All I know is, the ASP page decrypt this data in TSHAK, but I can't get to encrypt it in php.

The ASP that receives this encryption can't be modified, because it would cause other login system to be modified as well.

My code so far, in order to send this url with variables:

```
   $xmlurl = file_get_contents("http://172.16.192.25/?usuario=".$User."&pass=".urlencode($Pass));  
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlurl, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        if($xml=="Validado")
        {
        echo 'works';
        } 
            elseif($xml=="error") 
            {
                echo "doesn't work";            
            }
                else 
                {
                    "error 404";
                }
```

Comment: Are you sending to an [tag:asp-classic] or [tag:asp.net] page? "ASP" can refer to either, but they are two very different platforms and would get you two very different answers.

Comment: @AnonJr it is asp.net

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll have to leave it to someone in the .NET community to answer as that's not my area of expertise.